# Certificate problems since Let's Encrypts CA expired a few days ago

Tags: debian, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, lets-encrypt

I'm running a Debian 10 server and I can't connect to other machines using Let's Enccrypt certificates anymore since LE's CA (`DST Root CA X3`) expired a few days ago:

```
root#> curl -I https://example.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

What I've done so far:

- I updated the `ca-certificates` package
- I installed `libgnutls-openssl27` and `libgnutls30`
- I ran the `update-ca-certificates` command.

Still, the server is not able to establish a trusted connection to the target host. The LE certificate on the target host is fine, there are no SSL errors when I trigger `curl` from any other hosts.

How can I solve this problem and establish a trusted SSL connection? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check certificate on remote host, just to clarify issue. You could do it with openssl.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev Please read my question, I've done that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `curl` error related to certificate. there could be some issues with it. You should check certificate state directly from machine where you have problem.

Comment: @manifestor curl doesn't give you enough detail to find the problem. You need to use something like the openssl binary to get the full certificate chain. Try something like this `</dev/null openssl s_client -connect example.org:443`.

Answer (score 2):

Disable "DST Root CA X3" the certificate on your server. Run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

On the first screen that prompts "Trust new certificates from certificate authorities?" choose "yes". On the next screen press the down arrow key on your keyboard until you find `mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt`, press the space bar to deselect it (the `[*]` should turn into `[ ]`) and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

The symlink CA certificate of the new Let's Encrypt CA was missing in `/etc/ssl/certs` and it was commented out in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`. I created it by running:

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs && ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ISRG_Root_X1.crt ISRG_Root_X1.pem
```

Everything has been working fine since then. You can run `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` to activate it as well.